Getting error while uploading file saying operation is not allowed due to a security policy in your organization
while uploading a file 
i am getting this error while using out of the box file upload in salesforce education cloud.  this tries to upload a file related to application being submitted by applicant.

Check the file upload and download settings in your org. - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=experience.admin_files_type_security.htm&type=5
